# mutableStateOf() not assinging new object?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list, compose-recomposition

I am `updating` the old `mutableStateOf()` object data by modifying it but new data is not reflecting on it.

**variable: as**

```
val offTime = mutableStateOf<List<OffTime>>(emptyList())
```

**update code**

```
fun updateOffTime(newOffTime: OffTime, index: Int){
        val updatedOffTime = offTime.value.mapIndexed { i, offTime ->
            var result = offTime
            if(index == i) result = newOffTime
            result
        }
        offTime.value = updatedOffTime
        Log.d(TAG, "updateOffTime: $updatedOffTime")
        Log.d(TAG, "updateOffTime: ${offTime.value}")
    }
```

`Note:`   It works when the object `OffTime` is without `id`
i.e. `OffTime(fromTime, toTime)` :- works

OffTime(id,fromTime, toTime) :- doesn't works

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly your use-case, neither your entire code implementation, but if I may ask why are you using an ordinary `collection` `list` instead of a `SnapshotStateList` or an extension of its new instance, `mutableStateListOf` when its part of your requirement to perform list operations?

Have you tried converting your `offtime` as a `SnapshotStateList` like this?

```
val offTime = mutableStateListOf<OffTime>(mutableStateListOf())
```

and performing updates liks this?

```
offTime.add( ... )
//or
offtime.remove(...)
//or
offTime[index] = offtime copy
//or
var offTimeIterator = offTime.lisIterator() // where you can safely modify indeces
```

`SnapshotStateList` is created exactly for such `use-cases` in compose, where you can perform normal list operations such as (add, remove, update, or batch updates) and guarantees `re-composition`.

Your call

```
offTime.value = updatedOffTime // if this is a new instance of a list
```

will trigger an entire re-composition as the entire list reference had been changed, but with `SnapshotStateList`, any changes to the structure is guaranteed to match a specific `re-composition`, say if you modify an item at index 7, and if this is observed by say a `LazyColumn` only `LazyColumn's` 7th index will `re-compose`

Also I don't know if your `Offtime` is a `data class` or a standard class, I would recommend it to be a `data-class` so you can easily `copy()` a certain instance of it, pass a new value to a certain property of it and re-assign it in a `SnapshotStateList`.